Adding anything after category page URL needs to be ignored
I want to change behavior of Magento Category page URL. For example, if the category page URL is https://magento246p4-beta.com/gear/bags, I want to ensure that any additional text after "bags/" is ignored. For instance, the URL https://magento246p4-beta.com/gear/bags/filter/200 should display the content from https://magento246p4-beta.com/gear/bags without showing a 404 error. I do not want to redirect; I just want the page to load with the relevant category data.

Create di.xml file
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\UrlRewrite\Model\UrlFinderInterface">
        <plugin name="custom_url_rewrite_plugin" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\UrlFinderPlugin" sortOrder="1"/>
    </type>
</config>


Create a plugin file UrlFinderPlugin.php
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

use Magento\UrlRewrite\Model\UrlFinderInterface;
use Magento\UrlRewrite\Service\V1\Data\UrlRewrite;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;

class UrlFinderPlugin
{
    public function aroundFindOneByData(
        UrlFinderInterface $subject,
        callable $proceed,
        array $data
    ) {
        // Implement your logic here to modify $data as needed
        if (isset($data[UrlRewrite::REQUEST_PATH])) {
            $requestPath = $data[UrlRewrite::REQUEST_PATH];
            
            // custom logic to remove string after 2 slashes and continue
        }

        // Proceed with original method
        return $proceed($data);
    }
}



Ideally, you should not do this.
Reasons

Whenever we hit the URL, Magento checks it across the Url Rewrite module.
If we make a condition and in the future, another category level is added, the current logic would be unoperatable.

However, we can still do this if the maximum category level is fixed (2 in the current scenario).
To achieve this, we need to put a condition while checking the URL to the rewrite table and if it doesn't match, try it again after omitting the last texts (check only the first 2 levels). In this way, it will check only the first 2 levels if the whole string fails to match the rewrite entry.
Please let me know if you need assistance with this logic.

Thanks so wat would be the class where Magento is checking into rewrite table? I can take a look accordingly.

@TejasVyas, Magento\UrlRewrite\Model\UrlFinderInterface class. I have added plugin file in the answer.
